# Hibernate Session is closed

Tags: hibernate, session

When I call the method session.begin transaction as follows:

```
//session factory is instantiated via a bean
Session session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
```

Then I get the following exception message

```
6:13:52,217 ERROR [STDERR] org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:49)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1319)
```

What could be the cause of this error ?

Comment: What do you do _before_ that exception? Post the code, please.

Comment: Right now, Its like a mystery movie.

Comment: how did you obtain the session?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update:** I guess that calling `getCurrentSession()` does not guarantee that the session is actually open. For the very first time, you should use

```
Session session = this.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
```

instead. This suggestion is actually consistent with the page you found.

**Earlier:**

Based on the information available so far, we can conclude that the cause of the error is the session not being open ;-)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession

Answer (score 8):

I think I found the answer in:

[Session is Closed](http://www.17od.com/2006/11/06/using-managed-sessions-in-hibernate-to-ease-unit-testing/)

I am yet to implement it

Answer (score 7):

You can use this annotation on your controller method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

Comment: The attribute readOnly is undefined for the annotation type Transactional

Comment: I was refering to this `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of closing the session completely, you can use `session.disconnect()`, do some other work, then `session.reconnect()` before doing other transactions.

`session.close()` would be called at the very end of the request / business process.

In Hibernate 2.1.8 we have been using the one session per request model and it works well, avoiding session leaks, etc.

See [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/hibernate2/2.1.8/reference/transactions.html) for some elaboration

Answer (score 0):

This may be the reason

```
session.close();
tx.commit();
```

The correct way would be:

```
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: tx.commit() , will flush the session & also close the session implicitly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Hibernate Session Closed Problem a year ago . [MY QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139378/hibernate-session-closed-problem)

but it was for a different reason, I put this here in case someone faces this problem and wants to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

To handle session is closed exception:

1-)In your hibernate.cfg file change the default `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to `managed` instead of `thread`

2-)Create two methods to open and close the session properly and use the before and after your query as sown below:

```
 public static void renewSession() {
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
             ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
             session.beginTransaction();
       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void closeSession()
    {
       try {
       ManagedSessionContext.unbind(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory());
                  session.flush();
                 session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
try {
                renewSession();
                String query = "from Table tb";
               data = (List<TypeObject>)session.createQuery(query).list();
                closeSession();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Enfermedad> obtenerEnfermedadesOrderByProcal() throws HibernateException {
    if (session==null)
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    if (!session.isOpen())
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    return session.createQuery("FROM Enfermedad AS e ORDER BY e.ordenPROCAL, e.id").list();
}
```