# Migrating form Hibernate3 to Hibernate4 keep getting nested transactions not supported

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-4.x, hibernate3

A week before we migrated the application from hibernate3 to hibernate4 every thing worked fine in hibernate3 but after migrating to hibernate4. I keep getting **nested transactions not supported**.

Below is my service layer which is calling the dao

```
public class LeaveApplicationService implementsSerializable,LeaveApplicationInterfaceService{
    @Autowired
    private LeaveApplicationInterfaceDao _leavApplicationInterfaceDao;
       //getter setter
    @Override
    public synchronized void clickOnAddLeaveButton(LeaveApplicationViewBean leaveApplicationViewBean) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory=(SessionFactory) ObjectFactory.getBean("sessionFactory");
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();


        try{
                leaveApplicationViewBean.get_employeeListObj().clear();
                leaveApplicationViewBean.get_leaveTypelist().clear();
                leaveApplicationViewBean.get_leaveApproveers().clear();
                //leaveApplicationViewBean.set_employeeListObj(get_leavApplicationInterfaceDao().getEmployeeList());
                leaveApplicationViewBean.set_leaveTypelist(get_leavApplicationInterfaceDao().getLeaveType());
                leaveApplicationViewBean.set_leaveApproveers(get_leavApplicationInterfaceDao().getLeaveApprover(CmsUtil.getSession("userId").toString()));

        }catch(Exception e){
            CmsLogger.errorLog(LeaveApplicationService.class, e);
        }finally{
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
        }
}
```

The Dao layer

```
public class LeaveApplicationDao extends TransactionService implements Serializable,LeaveApplicationInterfaceDao{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6237725881698448330L;

    public List<LeaveApprover> getLeaveApprover(String userId) throws Exception {
      List<LeaveApprover> _leavApprovers=new ArrayList<LeaveApprover>();
      Iterator it=getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql.toString()).setParameter("practiceAreaId",CmsUtil.getSession("practiceAreaId").toString())                                            .setParameter("userId",userId).setCacheable(true)
                                                                                    .list().iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()){
        Object[] obj=(Object[]) it.next();
        LeaveApprover leaveApprover=new LeaveApprover();
        leaveApprover.set_approverId((String) obj[0]);
        leaveApprover.set_approverName((String) obj[1]);
        _leavApprovers.add(leaveApprover);
    }

    return _leavApprovers;
}



public List<TimeProjectCategory> getLeaveType() throws Exception{
    List<TimeProjectCategory> timeProjectCategories=new ArrayList<TimeProjectCategory>();
    Iterator it =getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql.toString()).setCacheable(true).list().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Object[] obj=(Object[]) it.next();
            TimeProjectCategory category=(TimeProjectCategory) ObjectFactory.getBean("domainTimeProjectCategoryObj");
            category.getProjectId().set_projectId((String) obj[0]);
            category.setTimeCategory((String) obj[1]);
            category.setTimeProjectCategoryId((String) obj[2]);
            timeProjectCategories.add(category);
        }


    return timeProjectCategories;

}

}
```

And my TransactionService class

```
public class TransactionService{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3747504246445270484L;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}


public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}


}
```

And the exception I see in the stack-track is

[Stack Trace for the code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pn9m8h9wqr4vw72/stack%20trace.txt)

My db.xml

[db.xml file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j125zqndt4nwbsg/db.xml)

Comment: Check the updates added in hibernate4 http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/WhatsNewInHibernateCore40

Comment: I don't see work around for the given code.

Comment: Hibernate never supported nested transactions, and that this was enforced in Hibernate 4. As AbstractTransactionImpl didn't exist before. Check out this same issue similar to your http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Migrating-Hibernate-4-facing-issue-50472.S.108439692

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception. Also, your service method starts a transaction, but doesn't commit nor rollback it.

Comment: As I use just to fetch the records nothing is to commit and rollback.

Comment: I have linked the stack-trace  Please help me out.

Comment: Could you post your spring transaction configuration? Have you specified any propagation level there while configuring the data source or tx manager? Or maybe inside your app server?

Comment: My db.xml https://www.dropbox.com/s/j125zqndt4nwbsg/db.xml

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

**Implementation-defined behavior with open transactions on session close:**

Make sure you commit (or rollback, doesn't matter for read-only) the transaction before closing the connection. Hibernate `Session.close()` closes the underlying connection; and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29 states that the behavior when a transaction is open is implementation-defined (i.e. some implementations will automatically close the transaction, others may reference count the connection and hold it open).

The general pattern is:

```
try {
    Transaction t = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    try {
        // do work
        t.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        t.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
} finally {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
}
```

**A previous transaction is still active:**

If a previous transaction is still active from somewhere else, you can do this:

```
Transaction t = session.getTransaction();
if (t == null || !t.isActive()) 
    t = session.beginTransaction();

// then use t (or session's current transaction, same thing)
```

Or, if you're not passing the `Transaction` around:

```
if (session.getTransaction() == null || !session.getTransaction().isActive())
    session.beginTransaction();

// then use session's current transaction
```

But you will still probably want to examine your code to see where else a transaction is being opened on a given connection.

Comment: According to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession getCurrentSession() will do it automatically. It will flush and close the connection . so I should not be worried about that.

Comment: I don't see that written anywhere in that link; the JDBC documentation is clear. Have you tried it? In any case I added a second possibility to the answer.

Comment: I haven't used spring transaction propagation attribute. So what you suggest me to use.

Comment: @JasonC may be right (beside that the JDBC documentation id clear, that post in the forum is simply too old). So simply try and tell us the response.

Comment: If this advice does not help, try updating/downgrading your hibernate version to a different minor version.