# Struts2: unable to load HibernateSessionFactory.getSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, jboss

I am running an application on JBoss server which is developed using struts2 & Hibernate.
But I am facing a problem in my getEmployee method of  LoginDAOImpl class.The code is as below:-

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UserView> getEmployee(String empId) {
    Session session = null;
    List<UserView> list = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 1 ");
        session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        System.out.println("in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 2 " + session);
        String str = "from UserView  where empId='" + empId + "'";
        list = session.createQuery(str).list();
        System.out.println("LoginDAOImpl.getEmployee()::" + empId);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
    }
    return list;
}
```

On Console Iam getting "in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 1 " but i am not getting "in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 2 ".That means it is not able to find Hibernatesessionfactory class.But I have included Hibernatesessionfactory in my path.
I have included jars for Hibernate :-
hibernate3.jar,hibernate-annotations-3.2.1.ga.jar,hibernate-annotations.jar,hibernate-commons-annotations.jar,hibernate-entitymanager.jar,hibernate-valid

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
session = HibernateSessionFactory.openSession();
```

Comment: Actually in my HibernateSessionFactory class there is no openSession method..so it is showing error after writing

Answer (score 0):

You can give something like :

```
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<UserView> getEmployee(String empId) {
                private static SessionFactory factory; 
                 try{
                      factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                 }catch (Throwable ex) { 
                    System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
                     throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
                 }

            Session session = null;
            List<UserView> list = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 1 ");
                session = factory.openSession();
                System.out.println("in LoginDAOImpl getEmployee : 2 " + session);
                String str = "from UserView  where empId='" + empId + "'";
                list = session.createQuery(str).list();
                System.out.println("LoginDAOImpl.getEmployee()::" + empId);
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Refer this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession) and **[link2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm)** for more details .

Comment: after adding the above code i am still facing some exception but is different frm previous one:-

Comment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     com.Allied.dao.LoginDAOImpl.getEmployee(LoginDAOImpl.java:153)
     com.Allied.service.LoginServiceImpl.getEmployee(LoginServiceImpl.java:29)
     com.Allied.action.LoginAction.loginCheck(LoginAction.java:101)
     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: root cause       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:189)
     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:112)
     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:105)
     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:235)
     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:208)
     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:221)
     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:151)

Comment: Can you give the code of your configuration file (xml file ) also , with your question ?

Comment: here is my config file:-

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    
    <!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.-->
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
     <property name="connection.username">root</property>
     <property name="dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
     </property>
     <property name="connection.password">root</property>

Comment: <property name="connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.90:3307/esupport
     </property>
     <property name="connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     </property>
     <property name="show_sql">true</property>
     
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.ActionView" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.LeaveDto" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.LeaveTypeDto" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.RoleActionMap" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.RoleView" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.TimesheetTask" />

Comment: <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.UserRoleMap" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.UserView" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeDetailsDto" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeLeave" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.ItdfDetails" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.Project" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeER" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.EmployeeTimesheet" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.ExpenseReportDto" />
     <mapping class="com.Allied.dto.TRStatusDto" />
    </session-factory>
    
    </hibernate-configuration>

Comment: It will be better , if you update your question with this configuration details NOT AS COMMENT (for better readability).