# JPA / JTA / @Transactional Spring annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, annotations

I am reading the transaction management Using Spring framework. In first combination I used Spring + hiberante and used Hibernate's API's to control the transaction (Hibenate API's). Next, I wanted to test using `@Transactional` annotation, and it did work.

I am getting confused on:

1. Do JPA , JTA, Hibernate have their "own" way of transaction
   management. As an example, consider if I use Spring + Hibernate, in
   that case would u use "JPA" transactions?

   Like we have JTA, is it true to say we can use Spring and JTA to
   control transactions?
2. The `@Transactional` annotation, is that specific to Spring
   Framework? From what I understood, this annotation is Spring
   Framework specific. If this is correct, is `@Transactional` using
   JPA/JTA to do the transaction control?

I do read online to clear my doubts, however something I don't get direct answer. Any inputs would be great help.

Comment: The `@Transactional` annotation is in two packages: `javax.transaction` and `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` so i guess there is JTA/JPA transaction handling and Spring transaction handling or spring implement the JPA/JTA transaction handling

Comment: Thanks for your info. Behind the scenes is "org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional" Spring's own way of transaction mechanism or using JPA or JTA?

Comment: What is your context configuration? What transaction manager do you use?

Comment: Please refer to this question that i asked earlier, there it has all the code/conf files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596489/hibernate-spring-4-x-and-transactional-annotation

Answer (score 13):

`@Transactional` in case of `Spring->Hibernate` using `JPA` i.e.

`@Transactional` Annotations should be placed around all operations that are inseparable.

So lets take example:

We have 2 model's i.e. `Country` and `City`.
Relational Mapping of `Country` and `City` model is like one Country can have multiple Cities so mapping is like,

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="country")
private Set<City> cities;
```

Here Country mapped to multiple cities with fetching them Lazily.
So here comes role of `@Transactinal` when we retrieve Country object from database then we will get all the data of Country object but will not get Set of cities because we are fetching cities LAZILY.

```
//Without @Transactional
public Country getCountry(){
   Country country = countryRepository.getCountry();
   //After getting Country Object connection between countryRepository and database is Closed 
}
```

When we want to access Set of Cities from country object then we will get null values in that Set because object of Set created only this Set is not initialize with there data to get values of Set we use `@Transactional` i.e.,

```
//with @Transactional
@Transactional
public Country getCountry(){
   Country country = countryRepository.getCountry();
   //below when we initialize cities using object country so that directly communicate with database and retrieve all cities from database this happens just because of @Transactinal
   Object object = country.getCities().size();   
}
```

So basically `@Transactional` is **Service can make multiple call in single transaction without closing connection with end point**.

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: Is .size() compulsory?

Comment: @LaHai yes, to fetch data