# Lazy initialization @ManyToMany. What is the error?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, lazy-initialization

Please, Help me implement lazy initialization.

I wrote Java code in Spring Core, Spring Security, and Hibernate. There are two user and Role entities. I link them with `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`. But for the task, I need to implement lazy initialization.

If I set `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`, an error occurs after successful authorization:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: web.model.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Google directed to these links: [First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164215/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-manytomany-relation) / [Second Link](https://botproxy.net/docs/how-to/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-userauthorities-could-not-initialize-/)

It suggests adding the `user.getAuthorities () method.size();`.

**Isn't this a workaround???**

Then authorization is successful, but with lazy initialization, I can't access the roles. And they don't appear on the jsp page.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An error occurred during processing [/WEB-INF/pages/admin_panel.jsp] in line [71]

68:             <td>${user.lastName}</td>
69:             <td>${user.username}</td>
70:             <td>${user.password}</td>
71:             <td>${user.roles}</td>
72:             <td>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:617)
```

**Below I will present the main parts of the code. If something is missing, then let me know.**

My code:

> User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // there was an EAGER here.
@JoinTable(name="user_role",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="roleId")})
private Set<Role> roles;

public User() {
}
...
```

> class UserServiceImp

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void add(User user) {
        userDao.add(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        return userDao.listUsers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean deleteUserById(long id) {
        return userDao.deleteUserById(id);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User getUserById(long id) {
        return userDao.getUserById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(User user) {
        userDao.update(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.getUserByName(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        int size = user.getAuthorities().size(); //added this line as indicated in the links
        return user;
    }
}
```

> page *.jsp

```
...
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td>${user.id}</td>
        <td>${user.firstName}</td>
        <td>${user.lastName}</td>
        <td>${user.username}</td>
        <td>${user.password}</td>
        <td>${user.roles}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="<c:url value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/editUser?id=${user.id}'/>" >Edit</a>
            |
            <a href="<c:url value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/deleteUser/${user.id}'/>" >Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
...
```

> UserDaoImp

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImp implements UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

   ...

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public User getUserByName(String username) {
        Query query = manager.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.username = : username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        try {
            return (User) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `FetchType.LAZY` does is that it doesn't take the entity collection (or entity in some cases e.g. `@OneToOne`) it is applied to when the entity containing it is returned from the db. It makes an additional request to *fetch* it later **if** its getter method is called **in the same transaction**. The workaround you found works because you call the getter `getRoles()` within `getAuthorities()` (although you haven't added that to the question) therefore fetching the set of roles explicitly.

After that you try to access a list of users which I assume you get from `public List<User> listUsers()` and if you understood the above paragraph you probably already know what I am going to say. In that method you don't fetch the roles, leave the transaction and then try to access the roles with `<td>${user.roles}</td>`. Now there are a few possible solutions to this problem.

- First off it is usually not a great idea to send entities to the frontend because that way you introduce unnecessary coupling. What I would suggest is you make a `UserDto` class which contains all the fields you will need to display (but not a single one more) which has a Set of `RoleDto` to which the same things apply and you convert your list of users you get from the db into a list of user dtos in the `listUsers()` method. That way you solve 3 problems -> 1. your code is decoupled 2. you eliminate data redundancy (e.g. unnecessary for the frontend db fields) 3. you fetch every user's roles when converting from users to user dtos.
- Another option would be to separate the `User` entity from the class implementing `UserDetails` by adding a new class to implement it. You can then add to this class on login all the information spring needs which basically means to transfer the necessary information from the `User` class to this new `UserDetailsImpl` class in the `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method so that all methods inherited by the `UserDetails` interface could be adequately implemented. From that point on any validation of roles or authorities will pass through the **non-entity** `UserDetailsImpl` which will eliminate the need for your workaround and the class will never throw a `LazyInitializationException` because it's not an entity. But copying fields like `firstName` and `lastName` from `User` is highly discouraged because of the possible data discrepancy.
- (NOT recommended) If you are feeling really lazy you can always just do the exact same workaround in the `listUsers()` method and just iterate trough the users and call their `getRoles()` method to fetch the roles.
- And lastly I understand that for whatever reason you can't do this and that's why I left this point for last but if you have to on many occasions access a collection of an entity outside of a transaction then `FetchType.EAGER` is clearly the easiest and best option. This is literally the problem it's made to solve.