# Play Framework + Spring Data JPA : LazyInitializationException

Tags: spring, jpa, playframework, spring-data

These are the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class Question {
   @Id
   public Long id;
   public String name;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName = "QUES_ID")
   public List<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Named
@Singleton
public interface QuestionRepository extends CrudRepository<Question , Long> {
    Question findByName(String name);
}
```

And in the Controller file I have this following File

```
@Transactional
public Result getQuestion() {
    List<Choices> list = this.questionRepository.findByName("name").choices;
    list.size();
    return ok();
}
```

list.size() in getQuestion() throws me a LazyInitializationException because there is not open sessions

I know that changing the fetch type to EAGER or using a JPQL query above the function definition in QuestionRepository might solve it, but there are part in my application where those wont help and I would require to lazy fetch.

How would make the entire code in getQuestion() function use a single session/transaction or even better my entire request to take place in an single session/transaction?

Comment: i think spring can't begin a transaction in `getQuestion` and you're just using the Spring Data's intertanl transactions.

Comment: All `Repository` implementations are Transactional by default. when you're calling `findByName`, spring begins a transcations and when the method returns, transaction commits and since your session is closed, `list.size()` throws `LazyInitializationException`. check play/spring integration..

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611173/jpa-jta-transactional-spring-annotation/26615390#26615390

Answer (score 2):

From [Spring Data JPA reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactional-query-methods)

> #### 4.7.1. Transactional query methods
>
> To allow your query methods to be transactional simply use `@Transactional` at the repository interface
>   you define.
>
> *Example 100. Using @Transactional at query methods*
>
> ```
> @Transactional(readOnly = true)
> public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
>
>     List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);
>
>     @Modifying 
>     @Transactional
>     @Query("delete from User u where u.active = false")  
>     void deleteInactiveUsers();
> }
> ```
>
> Typically you will want the `readOnly` flag set to `true` as most of the query methods will only read data. In contrast to that `deleteInactiveUsers()` makes use of the `@Modifying` annotation and overrides the transaction configuration. Thus the method will be executed with `readOnly` flag set to `false`.

*So just add @Transactional annotation to your repository interfaces.*

Comment: as mentioned about I want a solution without @Query, a solution that makes the session/transaction available outside the UserRepository.

Comment: Query is not needed, just add Transactional to interface.

Comment: adding Transactional dint work, getQuestion is a member of my controller class and not repository interface anyway

Comment: Check propagation of transaction, basically you want your transaction on Repository and method to be with REQUIRED propagation.

Comment: I would love a more elaborate explanation, A link would help me very much. Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html
Actually REQUIRED is a default configuration. Check youhave transactions enabled in your Spring configuration (@EnableTransactionManagement or <tx:annotation-driven/> is present)? And leave it just @Transaction in both places.