# Why does spring jpa ignore javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY and javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraph?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have a basic "Department"/"Employee" example.

Full example here (in master branch) : https://github.com/granadacoder/jpa-simple-example-one.git

If you setup 4 environment variables (listed in the README), the code is runnable/debuggable.

For my "findAll()" method, I am trying to only bring back the scalars of the Department entity.  (key and name).  Aka, I do NOT want any child Employees to be tacked onto the Department .. when I do a findAll().

I have tried using an name EntityGraph, but it is not working (I still get the full object graph)

I am using FetchType.LAZY as well. (which should have been enough IMHO)...  And I am not calling (department) .getEmployees at all.

But I took the extra step of defining and using "departmentJustScalarsEntityGraphName".

```
    @EntityGraph("departmentJustScalarsEntityGraphName")
    List<Department> findAll();
```

The above is loading the entire graph (all department scalar AND the employees) and doing it in an N+1 manner.  :(
The @EntityGraph should only be loading the key and name for the findAll() method.

If you find the code comment

```
/* right here, desperately hoping for each Department in the "entities" to NOT have employees hydrated */
```

you can put the debugger there and see the issue.

Note, that when I do a "find by single" (findById(key) or findDepartmentByDepartmentNameEquals(name))......I **DO** want the employees.  So answers that broad stroke disassociate the Employees are not ideal.

No matter what I've tried, I'm getting the N+1 issue. (The sample seed data has three Departments.)

```
Hibernate: select department0_.DepartmentKey as departme1_0_, department0_.CreateOffsetDateTime as createof2_0_, department0_.DepartmentName as departme3_0_ from DepartmentTable department0_
Hibernate: select employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey as departme6_1_0_, employees0_.EmployeeKey as employee1_1_0_, employees0_.EmployeeKey as employee1_1_1_, employees0_.CreateOffsetDateTime as createof2_1_1_, employees0_.FirstName as firstnam3_1_1_, employees0_.LastName as lastname4_1_1_, employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey as departme6_1_1_, employees0_.Ssn as ssn5_1_1_ from EmployeeTable employees0_ where employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey=?
Hibernate: select employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey as departme6_1_0_, employees0_.EmployeeKey as employee1_1_0_, employees0_.EmployeeKey as employee1_1_1_, employees0_.CreateOffsetDateTime as createof2_1_1_, employees0_.FirstName as firstnam3_1_1_, employees0_.LastName as lastname4_1_1_, employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey as departme6_1_1_, employees0_.Ssn as ssn5_1_1_ from EmployeeTable employees0_ where employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey=?
Hibernate: select employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey as departme6_1_0_, employees0_.EmployeeKey as employee1_1_0_, employees0_.EmployeeKey as employee1_1_1_, employees0_.CreateOffsetDateTime as createof2_1_1_, employees0_.FirstName as firstnam3_1_1_, employees0_.LastName as lastname4_1_1_, employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey as departme6_1_1_, employees0_.Ssn as ssn5_1_1_ from EmployeeTable employees0_ where employees0_.DepartmentForeignKey=?
```

Here are the main code components:

Department.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.mycompany.organizationdemo.domain.constants.OrmConstants;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedAttributeNode;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraph;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraphs;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;



@Entity
@NamedEntityGraphs({
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "departmentJustScalarsEntityGraphName", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("departmentKey"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("departmentName")})
})
@Table(name = "DepartmentTable")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DepartmentKey", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long departmentKey;

    @Column(name = "DepartmentName", unique = true)
    private String departmentName;

    @Column(name = "CreateOffsetDateTime", columnDefinition = OrmConstants.OffsetDateTimeColumnDefinition)
    private OffsetDateTime createOffsetDateTime;

    //region Navigation


    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "parentDepartment",
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY /* Lazy or Eager here */
    )

    private Set<Employee> employees = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    //endregion

    public long getDepartmentKey() {
        return departmentKey;
    }

    public void setDepartmentKey(long departmentKey) {
        this.departmentKey = departmentKey;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getCreateOffsetDateTime() {
        return createOffsetDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreateOffsetDateTime(OffsetDateTime createOffsetDateTime) {
        this.createOffsetDateTime = createOffsetDateTime;
    }

    //region Navigation
    public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
    //endregion


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Department that = (Department) o;

        return new org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder()
                .append(departmentKey, that.departmentKey)
                .append(departmentName, that.departmentName)
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
                .append(departmentKey)
                .append(departmentName)
                .toHashCode();
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
import com.mycompany.organizationdemo.domain.constants.OrmConstants;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;



@Entity
@Table(name = "EmployeeTable")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EmployeeKey", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long employeeKey;

    @Column(name = "Ssn")
    private String ssn;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "CreateOffsetDateTime", columnDefinition = OrmConstants.OffsetDateTimeColumnDefinition)
    private OffsetDateTime createOffsetDateTime;

    //region Navigation

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Department.class)//, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DepartmentForeignKey")
    private Department parentDepartment;
    //endregion


    public long getEmployeeKey() {
        return employeeKey;
    }

    public void setEmployeeKey(long departmentKey) {
        this.employeeKey = departmentKey;
    }

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getCreateOffsetDateTime() {
        return createOffsetDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreateOffsetDateTime(OffsetDateTime createOffsetDateTime) {
        this.createOffsetDateTime = createOffsetDateTime;
    }

    //region Navigation

    public Department getParentDepartment() {
        return parentDepartment;
    }

    public void setParentDepartment(Department parentDepartment) {
        this.parentDepartment = parentDepartment;
    }

    //endregion


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Employee employee = (Employee) o;

        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(employeeKey, employee.employeeKey)
                .append(ssn, employee.ssn)
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
                .append(employeeKey)
                .append(ssn)
                .toHashCode();
    }
}
```

Spring JPA

```
import com.mycompany.organizationdemo.domain.entities.Department;
import com.mycompany.organizationdemo.domaindatalayer.interfaces.IDepartmentRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

public interface DepartmentJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long>, IDepartmentRepository {


    @EntityGraph("departmentJustScalarsEntityGraphName")
    List<Department> findAll();




    @Query("SELECT d FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees WHERE d.departmentName = :departmentName") /* this works because departmentName is a UNIQUE constraint...otherwise it might give back duplicate parents (Departments) */
    Optional<Department> findDepartmentByDepartmentNameEquals(@Param("departmentName") String departmentName);

    /* note the below, this is "lookup strategy".  see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods */
    Collection<Department> findByCreateOffsetDateTimeBefore(OffsetDateTime zdt);

    //@Query("SELECT d FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees WHERE d.departmentKey IN ?1")  /* here a Query will bring back repeat parent (Department) rows */
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"employees"})
    Collection<Department> findDepartmentByDepartmentKeyIn(Set<Long> departmentKeys);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    int deleteDepartmentByDepartmentKey(long departmentKey); /* suffers from N+1 problem */
}
```

and the repository (plain jane) interface

```
import com.mycompany.organizationdemo.domain.entities.Department;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

public interface IDepartmentRepository {

    List<Department> findAll();

    Optional<Department> findById(long key);

    Optional<Department> findDepartmentByDepartmentNameEquals(String departmentName);

    Collection<Department> findByCreateOffsetDateTimeBefore(OffsetDateTime zdt);

    Collection<Department> findDepartmentByDepartmentKeyIn(Set<Long> departmentKeys);

    Department save(Department item);

    int deleteDepartmentByDepartmentKey(long departmentKey);
}
```

I have found this:

[Spring Data JPARepository: How to conditionally fetch children entites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266952/spring-data-jparepository-how-to-conditionally-fetch-children-entites/33320923#33320923)

and this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs002.htm

Spring Boot is fairly new.  (from gradle settings in the project)

```
    spring_plugin_version = '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    springBootVersion = '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    slf4jVersion = "1.7.25"
    javaxInjectVersion = "1"
    javaxPersistenceApiVersion = "2.2"
    junitVersion = "4.12"
    mockitoVersion = "3.3.0"
    jacksonAnnotationsVersion = "2.11.0"
    modelMapperVersion = "2.3.7"
    commonsLangVersion = '3.7'
```

PS

I'm also using the "convert to Dto" trick (as seen here) : https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application  but the Department(orm-entity) is already hydrated by that point.  :(

Comment: Try adding @JsonIgnoreon attributes you don't to to load

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... and I did try this...but that did not work.     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "parentDepartment",
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY 
    )
    private Set<Employee> employees = new LinkedHashSet<>();