# Session is closed before concluding request in Spring MVC, get LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am taking the LazyInitializationException error when because in myController when I read the Lazy collections session is already closed. Is there any way to get it open as long as there is a request? As OpenSessionInView? What would be the best way?

I'm using the version of Spring Boot 1.3.0

Comment: You need to either extend the scope of transaction to the mentioned controller or perfom lazy fetch when reading the entity (it would be easy if you were executing JPQL). OSIV is not the best choice imo.

Comment: How extend scope in a @Controller? Thanks

Comment: The spring call the hashCode of my object and I get the Lazy error.

Comment: You can user @Transactinal for open session troughtout the logic refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611173/jpa-jta-transactional-spring-annotation/26615390#26615390

Comment: @Transaction is used by the Service layer only,  not? Can I  use this in @Controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need use the "open session in view" to keep the session open after the end of the transaction.

see [OpenSessionInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) or [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) for JPA

imho it's better than extending the scope of the transaction to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `jackson/hibernate` combination you can register the [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) module, and tweak the `Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` property to your liking. The default is `false` means that only already fetched properties will be serialized. Changing to `true` will force initialization of the lazy properties