# Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

```
   package com.ccdm.vo;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * ViewModel generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "lb", catalog = "ccdmdb")
public class LoadBal implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -767868186084580713L;
    private Integer lbID;
    @JsonIgnore
    private AppUser appUser;
    private ViewModel templates;
    private String lbname;
    private String lbdescription;
    private String lbtype;
    private int clientId;



    public LoadBal() {
    }

    public LoadBal(AppUser appUser, String lbname, String lbdescription, String lbtype, ViewModel templates,
            int clientId) {
        this.appUser = appUser;
        this.lbname = lbname;
        this.lbdescription = lbdescription;
        this.lbtype = lbtype;
        this.templates = templates;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        System.out.println(this.lbname);
        System.out.println(this.lbdescription);
        System.out.println(this.lbtype);
        System.out.println(this.templates);
        System.out.println(this.clientId);
    }



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "LB_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getlbID() {
        return this.lbID;
    }

    public void setlbID(Integer lbID) {
        this.lbID = lbID;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    public AppUser getAppUser() {
        return this.appUser;
    }

    public void setAppUser(AppUser appUser) {
        this.appUser = appUser;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VM_ID", nullable = false)
    public ViewModel getTemplates() {
        System.out.println("here2" + templates);
        return this.templates;
    }

    public void setTemplates(ViewModel VmTemplates) {
        System.out.println("here3" + VmTemplates);
        this.templates= VmTemplates;
    }


    @Column(name = "LB_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getlbname() {
        return this.lbname;
    }

    public void setlbname(String lbname) {
        this.lbname = lbname;
    }
    @Column(name = "LB_DESCRIPTION", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getlbdescription() {
        return this.lbdescription;
    }

    public void setlbdescription(String lbdescription) {
        this.lbdescription = lbdescription;
    }
    @Column(name = "LB_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getlbtype() {
        return this.lbtype;
    }

    public void setlbtype(String lbtype) {
        this.lbtype = lbtype;
    }
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID", nullable = false)
    public int getClientId() {
        return this.clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(int clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }



}














package com.ccdm.vo;
// Generated 19 Dec, 2016 5:50:57 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.0.CR1

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

/**
 * ViewModel generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_model", catalog = "ccdmdb")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class ViewModel implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7778681960884580713L;
    private Integer vmId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private AppUser appUser;
    @JsonIgnore
    private OperatingSystem operatingSystem;
    @JsonIgnore
    private VirtualMachine virtualMachine;
    private String name;
    private int clientId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<SolutionVmMap> solutionVmMaps = new HashSet<SolutionVmMap>(0);
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<LoadBal> VmTemplates = new HashSet<LoadBal>(0);

    public ViewModel() {
    }

    public ViewModel(AppUser appUser, OperatingSystem operatingSystem, VirtualMachine virtualMachine, String name,
            int clientId) {
        this.appUser = appUser;
        this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
        this.virtualMachine = virtualMachine;
        this.name = name;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public ViewModel(AppUser appUser, OperatingSystem operatingSystem, VirtualMachine virtualMachine, String name,
            int clientId, Set<SolutionVmMap> solutionVmMaps, Set<LoadBal> VmTemplates) {
        this.appUser = appUser;
        this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
        this.virtualMachine = virtualMachine;
        this.name = name;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.solutionVmMaps = solutionVmMaps;
        this.VmTemplates = VmTemplates;
        System.out.println("vmtem------" + VmTemplates);

    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "VM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getVmId() {
        return this.vmId;
    }

    public void setVmId(Integer vmId) {
        this.vmId = vmId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    public AppUser getAppUser() {
        return this.appUser;
    }

    public void setAppUser(AppUser appUser) {
        this.appUser = appUser;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OS_ID", nullable = false)
    public OperatingSystem getOperatingSystem() {
        return this.operatingSystem;
    }

    public void setOperatingSystem(OperatingSystem operatingSystem) {
        System.out.println("os" + operatingSystem);
        this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VIRTUAL_MACHINE_ID", nullable = false)
    public VirtualMachine getVirtualMachine() {
        return this.virtualMachine;
    }

    public void setVirtualMachine(VirtualMachine virtualMachine) {
        this.virtualMachine = virtualMachine;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID", nullable = false)
    public int getClientId() {
        return this.clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(int clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "viewModel")
    public Set<SolutionVmMap> getSolutionVmMaps() {
        return this.solutionVmMaps;
    }

    public void setSolutionVmMaps(Set<SolutionVmMap> solutionVmMaps) {
        this.solutionVmMaps = solutionVmMaps;
    }
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "templates")
    public Set<LoadBal> getTemplates() {
        return this.VmTemplates;
    }

    public void setTemplates(Set<LoadBal> VmTemplates) {
        this.VmTemplates = VmTemplates;
    }



}
```

well, I'm new to spring. When I try to compile these codes, I'm getting the below-mentioned error. so please help me to sort out this problem. Thanks in advance!

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:      com.ccdm.vo.ViewModel.templates, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.ccdm.infrastructure.model.CCDMResponse["content"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.ccdm.vo.ViewModel["templates"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ccdm.vo.ViewModel.templates, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: 
        \\\com.ccdm.infrastructure.model.CCDMResponse["content"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.ccdm.vo.ViewModel["templates"])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611173/jpa-jta-transactional-spring-annotation/26615390#26615390
This Answer will help you

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough details in your question to help you resolve it right away, however you should

- Google for `LazyInitializationException` - it's a common newbie problem. And it's a runtime exception, not compile time
- Read the docs of the framework you're using (pure Spring or Spring Boot, JPA) how to open a transaction/session
- Read about lazily initialized collections in JPA/Hibernate
- Make sure you either open session/transaction in view (usually anti-pattern) or put a `@Transactional` annotation on your code.

Looking at your code, you're trying to serialize JPA entity rihght away to JSON so open-session-in-view will work for you, however you need to be VERY CAREFUL. This pattern is useful only in very simple applications.

Comment: Comment from the OP (which I found in the edit queue for this answer) :  

Actually, I'm trying to get all the template name from a table from spring to angularjs using request and response mapping. when i do that i'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

`LazyInitializationException` is occurred while you getting `@ManyToMany` and `@OneToMany` objects

Hibernate is LAZY loading in case of(`@ManyToMany` and `@OneToMany`)
So while getting `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` relation objects you should first iterate in DAO layer , and get the data other wise it shows `LazyInitializationException`