# Spring Lazy loading

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading

There are many examples and documentations about @Lazy. Maybe I didn't get the point, but why should it ever be used? Instantiating a bean costs < 1 ms at startup. Using lazy loading for beans gives you a bunch of new integration tests. Furthermore it could be rather dangerous, when your application starts up with no errors and crashes on the first call to a lazy loaded bean. So why? Does anybody has got a good example?

Comment: Instantiating a bean costs < 1ms if the constructor (and the post-construct hooks) don't have much to do. But they might take much longer. Imagine a bean reading many files at startup, or connecting to a slow and rarely used external service. Loading eagerly by default is what you want most of the time, and it's a safer default, but that doesn't mean lazy can't be useful.

Comment: Read this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611173/jpa-jta-transactional-spring-annotation/26615390#26615390

Comment: Don't get the link to the other article

Answer (score 0):

Lazy initialization might be useful, when your `@Lazy` annotated component depends on some infrastructure to be properly initialized. So, for example, if you have a component which needs to download some files during startup, then it probably makes a lot of sense to annotate it with `@Lazy`. This way it doesn't try to download files (which takes a lot of time) when it's not going to be used for a while.

However, personally I think using lazy components often leads to a bad design. Think twice before you use it.

Comment: I don't know if I would use it in this scenario. Looking at Spring Boot Config Server (which is such a long run scenario) this could be deadly. I was thinking about scenarios, where the beans are not in Singleton scope. Let's say we got a statefull service, which is only called sometimes. Could this be a way to avoid unnecessary allocation of resources?

Comment: Well, in such case a simple factory is the way to go. Just ignore lazy loading and create a factory that will build instances of your service in the runtime. Thanks to factory you instantiate your services only when you really need it.