# Calling Method of another class from Recursion Method: Java

Tags: java, recursion, race-condition

I have two class as A and B-

Class A:- This class has getData method, which is used to get data from DB.

```
class A {
    public synchronized getData() {
       // get some data from database, in finally block close connection
    }
}
```

Class B:- Which has recursion method m(), inside this method I am calling the getData() of class A.

```
class B {
   m() {
      //some condition to terminate the recursion
      A a = new A();
      a.getData();
      m();
   }
}
```

**Error I am getting:-**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.getAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:1226) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]

For the first call of getData() method, I am able to get data from DB, but after second recursion onward I am getting the connection as closed. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update:**

I have DB Util method which is opening the connection each time when getData() method is calling. It's working fine if I am calling this without recursion method(many times) but if I am using recursion I'm getting error. Is any special case I have to handle for recursion method?

Comment: I believe here you can get your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884701/hibernate-c3p0-throws-nullpointerexception-at-newproxyconnection-commit

Comment: trying to use debugger to figure it out.

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan thanks! I have gone through the link which you have shared but it's didn't help me. In my case I have recursion method from where I am calling getData of another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error specifies that *connection is closed*. Also, in your comment `// get some data from database, in finally block close connection`, you have mentioned that you have closed the connection after use but, you didn't mentioned that if you are opening the connection in he `getData()` method or not.

I would suggest following:

Check if you are opening the connection in `getData()` method. If not then **either** open the connection in this method only(remove the code for opening connection from some other method) **or** don't close the connection after use in this method instead use a different method to close the connection as per need.

Check if connection resource is reusable.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I have DB Util method which is opening the connection each time when getData() method is calling. It's working fine if I am calling this without recursion method(many times) but if I am using recursion I'm getting error.

Comment: @rish Because in recursion the `getData()` method called very first time, it uses the connection and close it, so the connection is not available for further calls of `getData()` method. If you will call `getData()` method without recursion then this situation doesn't occurs. Try once as suggested then please comment your observation.

Comment: After looking into the code, have noticed my DBUtil class was giving the existing connection(which already closed). I come from Angular2 background, need to learn more about Java :) . Thanks!