# Understanding SessionFactory and Hibernate Sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am learning `Hibernate` now and I need help to understand how `Sessions` work. I have some methods in a class which I have given below.

I see there is a `getCurrentSession()` in `SessionFactory` class. So, it seems that only one `Session` can be "active" inside a `SessionFactory`. Is this `SessionFactory` like 
a queue of transactions where the transactions are completed in in order ? If yes, then 
is it possible to promote a transaction to a higher or lower priority ?

```
private static SessionFactory factory;  

//Get a hibernate session.
public static Session getSession(){
    if(factory == null){

        Configuration config = HibernateUtil.getConfiguration();
        factory = config.buildSessionFactory();

    }   
    Session hibernateSession = factory.getCurrentSession();
    return hibernateSession;
}

public static void commitTransaction(){
    HibernateUtil.getSession().getTransaction().commit();
}

public static void rollbackTransaction(){       
    HibernateUtil.getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

And some more methods that use `getTransaction()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SessionFactory`'s job is to hide the session creation strategy.  For example, in a web application, you probably want the `SessionFactory` to return create a `Session` the first time `getCurrentSession()` is called on a thread, and then return the same `Session` from that point forward for the duration of the request.  (Since you probably want to load customer data from that session, then maybe modify their account in that same session.)  Other times, you may want `SessionFactory` to create a brand new session every time you call `getCurrentSession()`.  So by hiding this decision behind the `SessionFactory` API, you simply write code that gets the `Session` from the factory and operates on it.

The `Session` is what handles transactions.  As you probably expect, transactions are started in a `Session`, and then either complete or rollback.  There is really no way to prioritize them since once they are started, you are committed to either rolling it back or committing it.

Comment: Yes, how do all the methods which call `factory.getCurrentSession()` know that they are getting access to the same `Session` ? One might wonder if `beginTransaction()` gets one session and `commitTransaction()` might get another, thereby making transactions useless. How do I know that I am dealing with the correct transaction ?

Comment: That depends on how the `SessionFactory` is configured.  `SessionFactory` will give you the 'correct' `Session`.  What 'correct' means, depends on your application.  As stated in the javadoc for `SessionFactory`: "Obtains the current session. The definition of what exactly 'current' means controlled by the CurrentSessionContext impl configured for use."  If you want to validate that it's doing what you think, then check the hashcodes of the returned sessions to make sure it is the same session.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way/method/function for a developer to tell the `SessionFactory` which kind of session to use ? A made up example - `SessionFactory.setCurrentDefinition(String mode)`. Here mode can be "same old session" or "brand new session".

Comment: The SessionFactory can be configured in the spring XML config. Define your session factory when you define your transaction manager and you can be sure that all your transactions will be using the session factory you configured.

Comment: James is right - it will either be in your Spring XML config (if you are using Spring) or in your Hibernate XML config if you are not (which seems to be your case).  Where this config actually resides depends on the implementation of `HibernateUtil.getConfiguration()` (HibernateUtil is not an official Hibernate class, so it just depends on how it is implemented - typically, it loads some XML files.)  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: @JamesMassey - I don't use spring now. But, can I use the XML config to make `SessionFactory` return the same `session` all the time or even different ones ? If that is true, then I'll read about it. Thanks.

Comment: @mattforsythe - Do you know which property of hibernate XML config can change/set which session is returned ? Thanks. Chenqui.

Comment: Check out the `current_session_context_class` property in the link to the documentation that I posted in my earlier comment.  Hope that helps.