# How to get results using Hibernate/Spring to JNDI DataSource?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and need help getting results from a JDNI dataSource.  Using JDBC I am able to view connection info like this.

```
    //jdbc
    conn = DbConnectionFactory.getConnection(ContextType.JNDI_WORKFLOW_DATA);
    log.info("Connnection INFO :" + conn);
```

Do I have to use the DbConnectionFactory for hibernate in order to view connection Info?  I have jndi datasource hibernateProperties in xml file like this.

```
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/env/jdbc/data</prop>
```

Whenever I try to get the results like this I get a QuerySyntaxException saying ReferenceModel is not mapped.  How do I map my RefernceModel?

```
    //hibernate
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<ReferenceModel> jsonData = (List<ReferenceModel>) session.createQuery("select State, from STATE").list();
```

Comment: Your class are declared with uppercase ? try something like "from State" and why you expect a list of ReferenceModel if you're doing a select in a STATE

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  I found the issue   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468602/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-createsqlquery-is-not-valid-without-active-tra).