# How do I map my Hibernate domain class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean and for some reason my packagesToScan doesn't map my domain class properly.  My server starts correctly with hibernate and I can get the session in my impl class.  However, when I try either createQuery, createCriteria, Hibernate template, etc I get a QuerySyntaxException saying the domain is not mapped.  The query is from class(domain), and not table.  What did I miss?  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you map the class with domain? if yes please insert in answer.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* Post the code and the error message.

Comment: Thanks guys.  This   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468602/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-createsqlquery-is-not-valid-without-active-tra) helped me solve my issue.