# Hibernate Spring @Transaction doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have the following:

```
@Service
public class AsyncMarketService {

    @Inject
    IdentifierManager identifierManager;

    @Transactional
    public void getProducts() {
        identifierManager.getTitleForIdentifier();
      }
}
```

The service method is being called from an @Async method.

I see in the log that the transaction is being opened:

```
134331 DEBUG [Company-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
134342 DEBUG [Company-1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.estartup.caller.AsyncMarketService.getProducts]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
134343 DEBUG [Company-1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b9b0793 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@ee6c9e deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4230dd40 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@5d5e00b collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56a1c8bd collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@25d8d46b collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@61c6c74d collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4b39a6c6 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
134346 DEBUG [Company-1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b9b0793 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@ee6c9e deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4230dd40 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@5d5e00b collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56a1c8bd collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@25d8d46b collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@61c6c74d collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4b39a6c6 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
134346 DEBUG [Company-1] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Company?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
134377 DEBUG [Company-1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@4d9068ae]
```

However, I still get an error:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
```

when I am trying to call from that method  (`identifierManager.getTitleForIdentifier();`) the DAO to retrieve something by id.

What is wrong?

**EDITED**

Configuration Bean:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.estartup" })
@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(env.getProperty("connection.url"), env.getProperty("connection.username"),
                env.getProperty("connection.password"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    public PersistenceConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = null;
        try {
            factoryBean = createBaseSessionFactory();
            factoryBean.getHibernateProperties().setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return factoryBean;
    }

    private LocalSessionFactoryBean createBaseSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties pp = new Properties();
        pp.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        pp.setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", "3");
        pp.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.estartup.*" });
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(pp);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the session being started in a different thread to the one executing the queries?

Comment: yes - I have a session in view filter that starts it in every call to my REST api

Comment: I've not used the Async annotation before, but I found this page  https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ and it says "The findPage method is flagged with Spring’s Async annotation, indicating it will run on a separate thread" so I suspect the seperate thread does not have the same session - just a guess

Comment: in that case - how can I solve it?

Comment: could you please show your hibernate configuration?

Comment: added the configuration

Comment: Don't mess around with the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` remove the setting of the property. Spring takes care of this for you. Your current setting `thread` breaks proper spring transaction management for hibernate.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using it as this is transaction for REST api that works per thread. I tried to remove it, but it didn't help

Comment: That shouldn't matter if you have your bounderaries correctly specified. What is async here btw? I don't see anything in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is to drop the @Transactional annotation and manually open a session yourself (not sure if there is a better way...)

```
@Service
public class AsyncMarketService {

    @Inject
    IdentifierManager identifierManager;

    @Inject
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void getProducts() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            identifierManager.getTitleForIdentifier();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If you find yourself doing this more than once, maybe write another component that has a method that takes a closure or something.

If I find a more elegant way in the next few minutes, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Dejel - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession

Comment: Looks like I forgot to start the transaction in this example!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the @Transactional to the calling asynchronous method. The transaction does not get propagated through the call hierarchy from one Spring component to the other, because the asynchronous method is being scheduled and executed at a later time by a task executor.