# What sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() does

Tags: java, hibernate

The [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html) says:

> A org.hibernate.Session begins when the first call to
>   getCurrentSession() is made for the current thread. It is then bound
>   by Hibernate to the current thread. When the transaction ends, either
>   through commit or rollback, Hibernate automatically unbinds the
>   org.hibernate.Session from the thread and closes it for you. If you
>   call getCurrentSession() again, you get a new org.hibernate.Session
>   and can start a new unit of work.

If the property `current_session_context_class` is set to `thread` then what exactly hibernate does? What does it mean when they say current thread?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession) says `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() returns a session bound to a context`, what it means exactly, can someone please clarify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate openSession() vs getCurrentSession()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession)

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary, the link explains clearly about openSession, but the information for getCurrentSession is not clear, what it means current thread, what exactly hibernate does in this scenario, can you please explain