# Which one is recommended for web application: sessionFactory.openSession() or sessionFactory.currentSession()?

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate

Which way to obtain a persistence session is recommended for web applications:

1. `sessionFactory.openSession()` or
2. `sessionFactory.currentSession()`

in Hibernate with Spring? And: Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate openSession() vs getCurrentSession()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession)