# Hibernate: Two or more transactions at the same time: Transaction already active

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jersey

I have a REST API and when I make a POST and a GET nearly the same time I get this exception:

```
 SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:409)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at utils.HibernateSession.createTransaction(HibernateSession.java:15)
    at api.ConversationsREST.getMessages(ConversationsREST.java:128)
```

They are on different classes so no global attributes implied.

The line which fails is this one:

```
HibernateSession hs = new HibernateSession();
hs.createTransaction(); // Crash
```

Which refers to my class HibernateSession:

```
public class HibernateSession {

    public Session session;

    public void createTransaction() {

        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); //THIS WAS WRONG
 //EDIT:session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); //THIS IS RIGHT
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    public void commitclose() {

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }

    public void rollbackclose() {

        try {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception hibernateexception) {
            hibernateexception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The exception is actually on the line `session.beginTransaction()`

I always make a hs.commitclose() and in the catch() blocks and the 404s I always make a rollbackclose();

The problem is that when I make a POST messages like this:

```
HibernateSession hs = new HibernateSession();
hs.createTransaction();
hs.session.save(whatever);
hs.commitclose();
```

Returns 200 and it's ok but then the GET may crash with the exception above.
As I am making a **new** instance of HibernateSession, why Hibernate seems to be trying to share that transaction?

This only happens when I make both queries in a very short time (I guess starting a transaction between the beginning and the commit of another one). So I guess Hibernate is thinking that session attribute is static or something like that...

### Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** As requested, `HibernateUtil.java` (the problem must not be here but may help to understand):

```
package utils;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        if (sessionFactory == null) {

            sessionFactory = build();

        }
        return sessionFactory;

    }

    private static SessionFactory build() {

        try {

            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed: " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can u add HibernateUtil as well...

Comment: @Ashish451 Of course

Comment: I have added solution.. you can try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per your `createTransaction` logic, you are getting current session from `SessionFactory` and starting a transaction from it.

*Here is the problem.*

Lets assume you have created `HibernateSession` object and started transaction but it is still in progress. So you haven't close transaction yet.

Now you created another `HibernateSession` and try to start transaction, doing this will throw exception.

So your this code

```
public void createTransaction() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
}
```

has to be this

```
public void createTransaction() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
}
```

**getSessionFactory().openSession()** always opens a new session that you have to close once you are done with the operations.

**getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()** returns a session bound to a context - you don't need to close this.

Comment: Using `getSessionFactory().openSession()` will work, but this will open a session for each call, it's a bad practice design, try not to make this. It will just kill the appplication when ther will be many calls.

Comment: I do agree with you but as per his input he is already creating new instance of HibernateSession.  I would rather let Container manage Sessions.

Comment: @cнŝdk spent lots of time now to circumvent it. opensession does not register to threadlocal. horrible design. all of hibernate really. i have solved it though using my own implementations, but i wonder. when you do get a new session using openSession() ...and begin a tranasaction .. will all new code like adding enitties belong to the new transaction? when we close it, do we get back to the previous one ? because who gets the work ? what decides that? is that a stack that depends on when the transaction starts and ends ?

Comment: Yes, it's a little bit confusing and too complicated part of hibernate, but afak when you close a `Transaction`, you should open a new one otherwise you won't be able to persist data, but when you open a new `Transaction` you should make sure to close it as well as yes all the new code changes (adding, editing entities) will be held in that transaction, until you `commit` it.

Comment: But always keep in mind that: **A session is not thread safe and should only be used by one thread. Usually this is guaranteed by the SessionFactory** as stated in [**Session and Transaction Handling** chapter](https://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch13.html) in Hibernate docs. 
And there will be no need to implement your own design if you are using **Spring** or **EJB**, `Transaction` will be perfectly handled by these Frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few design related flaws:

1. You should not use `getCurrentSession()`

As Stated in the jboss [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html), you should use the following idiom:

```
 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

2. You should follow the CRUD pattern

For each Operation (Create, Read, Update, Delete) create a method in your class. Each Method shall creates it's **own** session and transaction to work with, because as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8049227/3286178):

> session is not a thread safe object - cannot be shared by multiple
>   threads. You should always use "one session per request" or "one
>   session per transaction"

Your methods are somewhat valid, but also have a look at the DAO Objects created in [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-dao-example/)

**Solution:**

The reason your code is failing is simply because the Transaction is still in progress from your previous interaction with the database. That is why you do a `finally{ session.close() }` - to make **sure** that the session is closed when leavin the method. I assume that at some point your `commit()` was not successfull and left your hibernate in a Transaction/Session that has not been closed since.

To fix that, you should insert a session.close() once in your code, execute it and then implement my suggested try-catch-finally block to make sure it is closed in the future.

Comment: I changed getCurrentSession() with openSession()

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are many drawbacks in your actual code:

- You are creating a new instance of your `HibernateSession` class each time you call your code, so you will have many instances of it, trying to access the same session.
- Each of this instances of `HibernateSession`, will try to create a new transaction when you call `hs.createTransaction();`, and that's why you are getting the Exception at this line, because there are already open transactions and you are trying to open a new one, beacuse you are calling `session.beginTransaction();` each time without calling `transaction.close();`.

What you can do here is to make your `HibernateSession`class singleton, so only one instance is available, you can check this [**Singleton Pattern implementation**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm) for further details on how to implement it.

And in the `createTransaction` method, wich should be better named `getTransaction` instead of just calling `session.beginTransaction();` you need to get the current transaction if it exists you can check it using `session.getTransaction()` method and make sure you wrap your code in a `try ...catch` block, you can check this [**Hibernate session** tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_sessions.htm) for further details.

Comment: As one can see in his edit, he has a Singleton Factory that he can use to instanciate new Sessions, which would be totally fine. His actual error is that he has no `finally { session.close() }` or even `try{ .. }` in his committing method to begin with. That left his session open at some point and now he is stuck.

Comment: @rwenz3l Yes I know that the code behind is following a singleton pattern, but as he is making a new class to handle that, he should better make this in his class layer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

with

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

I was accessing the session of the Factory alredy opened.

Comment: It will work, but actually this will open a session for each call, it's a bad practice design, try not to make this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. In my case after the session was created, I had forgotten the instruction:

```
session.beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try re-writing the code as

```
public class HibernateSession {

    public Session session;
    int id;
    Transaction t = null;

    public void createTransaction() {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        t = session.beginTransaction();
    }

    public void commitclose() {
        t.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void rollbackclose() {

        try {
            t.rollback();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception hibernateexception) {
            hibernateexception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Off course null-checks are required for every reference of `t`.

Comment: Throwed the same exception but instead of session.beginTransaction(); it was on t = session.beginTransaction();

Comment: Last attempt. Replace `t = session.beginTransaction();` with `t = session.getTransaction();`

Comment: But I need to begin it. It should be inactive as the first time i  make a GET. I can check if is active or not, but that's only a workaround, what I really need is the transaction to be a very new instance every time the class is instanciated.

Comment: @CarlosLópez that's why you should use a session factory! You only have **one** instance of a Hibernate Session and that one got stuck inside a Transaction because you did **not** close it properly.

Comment: @nwenz3l I did, the problem was on the getCurrentTransaction() instead of the openTransaction i wanted to do.

Comment: There are lot of use-cases where you don't get the privilege of opening a new transaction for every operation. In enterprise environments, lot of times you have to join an a already existing transaction, because a transaction is very costly. It's a workaround indeed. Given your code, I felt it won't hurt that much.