# Get object using hibernate session without transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

What are differences between `getCurrentSession` and `openSession`?
I mean using openSession I could make retrieve from the DB without beginning the transaction and committing it.

```
final SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sf.openSession();

Student student = session.get(Student.class, 1);
System.out.println(student);

session.close();
sf.close();
```

But in `getCurrentSession`, I have to do `session.beginTransaction()` and `session.getTransaction().commit()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.openSession()** always opens a new session that you have to close once you are done with the queries. whereas **.getCurrentSession()** returns a session bound to a context - you don't need to close.

Comment: Okay but with openSession() I could make retrieve from the DB without beginning the transaction and committing it. How it that?

Comment: when we use .beginTransaction() that means we are maintaining our multiple transactions(queries). E.x. you have 3 queries associated with this transaction and if one of them fails then other will get roll-backed.